# What project files belong in a gem package?

Tags: ruby

I suppose the more specific question is: Do all project files belong in a gem package, so that a gem serves as a complete encapsulation of a project? Or should only the necessary files belong to make the gem functional? Or something in between?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to answer, since you have no specifics.

However, I would say the following types of things should be in the gem:

- The code for the gem. This lives in `gem/lib/gemname`.
- Tests. These go in `gem/test` or `gem/spec` typically.
- Executables, if any. They go in `gem/bin`.
- Documentation. Maybe in the code, maybe in `gem/doc`. At the very least (really too little) in the `README`.
- A license and a readme. These typically go in the gem's top level directory.
- A Rakefile. Typically at `gem/Rakefile`.

If you're asking specifically what files should be included in the `files` item for a gemspec, a typical one might look like this (taken from the [RubyGems Guides Specification Reference page](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#files)):

```
spec.files = FileList['lib/**/*.rb',
                      'bin/*',
                      '[A-Z]*',
                      'test/**/*'].to_a
```

You can get a lot more information from the [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant the later --what to add for spec.files. By your answer, it appears just the minimum. Not even sure tests really need to be included in that case.

Comment: What I have in the example spec isn't just the minimum. It's the code files in `lib` and `bin` (if any), plus things like a `README` and `LICENSE`, plus the tests in `test` (or `spec` if you prefer). You should include the tests, since users can then test your gem.